# how to get notice that one key has been created in redis

Tags: django, redis

I have a outer service which will insert data to redis(I can get the keys of the data),but this may take some times , so the question is, how can I get to know that the data is comming.I want to show that in a  page based django??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PUB/SUB of redis.

When your other service inserts new data, publish key on some channel...

So your django subscribes on channel "datachanged"

```
./redis-cli subscribe "datachanged"
```

And your service send event over channel

```
./redis-cli set "key:abc123" "some value"
./redis-cli publish "datachanged" "key:abc123"
```

Also you can use "Redis Keyspace Notifications" if your redis is newer then 2.8.0 (http://redis.io/topics/notifications)